# How can I export from Excel per workbook and page as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have a large Excel file which needs to be saved as a PDF. In each workbook I have 25 pages which I need to save as pdf.

Example: Workbook (x1) has pages (25). Now I need to create a PDF file for each page.

For this I have copied a code in VBA, which creates a PDF file for each workbook (Unfortunately not for each page separately).

**VBA Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportAsPDF()

Dim Folder_Path As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Select Folder path"
If .Show = -1 Then Folder_Path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

If Folder_Path = "" Then Exit Sub

Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Name & ".pdf"
Next

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExportAsFixedFormat` has parameter to specify the from- and to-page. Now all you need is to figure out the number of pages to be expected. This can be done using the `HPageBreaks.Count` and `VPageBreaks.Count`-property of the sheet - just keep in mind that you have to add 1 to those parameters (eg if a sheet has 2 horizontal breaks, it will result in 3 pages).

Using that, you simply export in a loop. Don't forget to add a suffix so every page gets a unique filename.

```
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim pageCount As Long, page As Long
    pageCount = (sh.HPageBreaks.Count + 1) * (sh.VPageBreaks.Count + 1)
    
    For page = 1 To pageCount
        sh.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Folder_Path & Application.PathSeparator & sh.Name & "_p" & page & ".pdf", from:=page, to:=page
    Next
Next
```